# Getting multiple inputs from one line from a file in c++

Tags: c++, string, file-io

Basically, I'm attempting to get three things from one line of code, read from a .txt file.  This will be repeated, but for now I only need to know how to get one line.  The line I'm reading looks like this:

```
Biology                 $11 12
```

So I want to get a string, and two ints, and completely ignore the $ (note, I cannot change the .txt file, so i have to leave the $ in)

So if I have

```
string subject;
int biologyscores[25];
```

The code I have is :

```
int biologyscores[25]; //array to store the integer values
std::string subject;   //string to store the subject the scores are for
std::ifstream infile("myScores.txt"); //declare infile to read from "myScores.txt"

infile >> subject >> biologyscores[0] >> biologyscores [1];  //read into string and int array
```

So the string will be used to check which subject these scores are for, and the scores themselves will be stored in an array biologyscores, indexed next to each other.

The problem is after this code executes, subject = "Biology" which is desired, but biologyscores at index 0 and 1 both seem to have junk numbers, not what I want to read into them.

Comment: Depending on your file format you may want to read a whole line into a std::string and parse the string. Also be careful of reading a string with `nfile >> subject` are all of your subjects exactly 1 word and have no chance of having a space character in them?

Comment: @drescherjm some subjects are multiple words

Comment: My suggestion is that you start by reading the whole line into a string. Then attempt to parse the string. This is usually easier (and a lot less error-prone).

Comment: I solved this problem, thanks eveyone for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dummy character variable which will "pick up" $ character:

```
char dummy_char;
infile >> subject >> dummy_char >> biologyscores[0] >> biologyscores [1];  //read into string and int array
```

Comment: this works for this input, thank you.  I am curious though, how to get it to work with subject being multiple words? ie. Computer Science

Comment: If the $ is always present, you can use it as the termination of the subject, whether one word or many.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **seekg** and **tellg**

```
    std::fstream infile("myScores.txt"); //declare infile to read from "myScores.txt"
int temp;
infile >> subject;   //read into string 
temp=infile.tellg(); //to get the position of $
infile.seekg(temp+1);// to move one step forward 
infile>> biologyscores[0] >> biologyscores [1];//now you can read the int values
```